# React native could not connect to development server

Tags: android, react-native

[image]

My steps which I followed till now are,

- react-native init FirstApp
- cd FirstApp
- started emulator from android studio
- react-native start FirstApp
- App started on emulator all fine
- and then i changed on android js file, saved it and pressed rr to reload and then the red screen appears

Things I have tried,

- running on different ports
- set the ANDROID_HOME variable pointing to sdk folder both for system as well as user variable

**I am working on windows os**

Comment: Can you check if the package server is still running, maybe it crashed after you made the change in your android js file?

Comment: Are you on device or emulator ?

Comment: i am on emulator

Comment: @dotcomXY it didnt crashed..

Comment: Have you try to build again with 'react-native run-android' and also run your server 'react-native start' simultaneously ?

Comment: yes, then the error comes you cannot run on this port. so i executed "react-native start --port=8088", to run the server on another port. Now, when i reload my app the app tries to connect to 8081 port and then again the above red screen appears.

Comment: Change the port from dev setting press CTRL+M and go to dev settings change the server host and port by clicking debug server host, now in your case it will be 10.0.2.2:8088, Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

close all terminals and then try this line in new terminal :

> adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

and then run the project again :

> react-native run-android